# Mapped types in function arguments

Tags: typescript

I have a list of screens in a file:

**file1.ts**

```
export const LANDING = 'landing.Landing'
export const REGISTER = 'landing.Register'
export const LOGIN = 'landing.Login'
```

and a list of props for each screens in another file

**file2.ts**

```
type LandingProps = { foo: string }
type RegisterProps = { bar: number }
type LoginProps = { baz: object }
```

I want to create a `navigate` function in another file such as:

**file3.ts**

```
import { LANDING, REGISTER, LOGIN } from 'file1'
import { LandingProps, RegisterProps, LoginProps } from 'file2'

const screens = [LANDING, REGISTER, LOGIN] as const
type ScreenType = typeof screens[number]

type Props = LandingProps | RegisterProps | LoginProps

function navigate(screen: ScreenType, props: Props) {
    console.log('Navigation to screen ', screen)
    console.log('Props are: ', props)
}
```

How can I type the argument `props` so that the props match the corresponding ScreenType ?

And on a side note, is it possible to create a type based on all the export from **file1** without having to specify which ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're excluding `LOGIN` from the screen types?  Is there a reason you're annotating `LANDING` etc as `string` instead of letting the compiler infer them as literal types?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAMgQQHIBECSSDiMC8MDkANgIZgAmAlmAOYB0cplN+AsAFCiSwBKAopmgDKAFV7dcBEuSp1uAU2oVocgE6sO4aPADyApBKKMZ9EIrDqoATwAOc+EZoAFFSGsQJAbxgAzECABcMNAqMjAAvuxWtjDyisoqzq7ueF4ARsQqgWAArgC2qarhkTZ2cKZUiW6eMOkAXoEgqQBWcsCwEWxUUKrexMB2gsAqcnJglRAAssTW1qEe7DAwANqIqBiYALqBDNJOLm4ANAvLfAIiYlsxCkrdCfsQR2yLK7oYl2Vm4+wd3tlgbRRwDAwMQAG4UajEboAHgA0jA5AAPbrkdwAazklhA3hgg2Go3GUxmMgAfAAKCBDEZgQKwg4waz3QJ46mE6azGhLWEbACUMC8HRB4Mh3TJq3QWHpXl8ARgACI5eEeQBuGAAejVMBAaOIlnYQohULkYuQEswUpqGUCAEYlaqNQiVC4VOwgA) work for you?

Comment: It's an error on my side. Fixed the example and removed the string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the compiler restrict the type of `props` based on the type of `screen`, you need to give it a mapping.  The easiest way to do that in your case is to make a dummy interface, since the types of `props` are already key-like:

```
interface ScreenPropsMapping {
  [LANDING]: LandingProps,
  [REGISTER]: RegisterProps,
  [LOGIN]: LoginProps
}
```

Because `LANDING` etc are `const` string literals, we can use them as [computed keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-5.html#computed-properties) in interfaces.

Then you give `navigate()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) signature like this:

```
function navigate<K extends keyof ScreenPropsMapping>(
  screen: K, props: ScreenPropsMapping[K]
) {


}
```

Here, `K` is constrained to be one of the keys of the mapping interface, and `props` is constrained to be the particular property type at that key:

```
navigate(LANDING, { foo: "" }); // okay
navigate(LANDING, { bar: 1 }); // error
```

---

As for your side note, if you really want a type to be the union of all the types of exported values in a module, you could do something like this:

```
import * as File1 from 'file1'
type File1Types = typeof File1[keyof typeof File1];
// type File1Types = "landing.Landing" | "landing.Register" | "landing.Login"
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-mRjlF+2HhCVkjA79iYGvHUsMVica+cR+Nk1Ud9Tvd8B0dR9bGfFU2xoegHGodUAB9VVgis4luZDUIQkwzBVb4gA)